# How do I go about with this git configuration which pushes to production from the private git server?

Tags: git

`Fedor` is my private git server, which houses a bare --init'd `repo.git` file.

`Vadim` is my production server, which houses a regular repo.

I need `Vadim` to only pull from `Fedor`. There is no "staging" or middle man. Developers will push to `Fedor` always, and I want `Fedor` to automatically, upon being pushed, hook up `Vadim` with the latest `repo.git`.

At this point, what I've done on `Fedor` is:

```
mkdir myrepo.git
cd !$
git --bare init
```

Then, locally I added `Fedor` as a remote origin and pushed to him. I setup a git repo on `Vadim` in `/var/www/html/foo/` and I added `Fedor` with:

```
git remote add origin git@FEDOR.com:repo.git
```

I have only used `git pull origin master` as this won't be doing any pushes. To reiterate, I want to automate the process so that when devs push to `Fedor`, some kind of hook is added so after pushing it automatically does a `git pull origin master` on `Vadim`.

I'm open to rearranging the way `Vadim` is setup, as it has a very primitive setup.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to push on Vadim, except you [shouldn't push to non-bare repo](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_won.27t_I_see_changes_in_the_remote_repo_after_.22git_push.22.3F).

Use a bare repo on Vadim, with  a **[post-receive hook](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)** ensuring the working tree is refreshed on any push:

```
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

That way, you can define a post-update hook on Fedor pushing automatically on the bare repo on Vadim.

Comment: Thanks for responding. So this means that Developer A would push to Fedor ( bare repo ) which pushes to Vadim ( bare repo ) and the post-receive on Vadim updates the work tree on Vadim locally? Is it somewhat counter-intuitive to having two clone bare repos or is it normal?

Comment: @meder: Any upstream repo where you need to *push* to should be a bare repo one, to avoid any synchronization issue between the working tree and its repo. This is the normal setup for any repo with a "centralized" role.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take which doesn't require an extra repository on `Vadim` is to have the hook on `Fedor` do a:

```
git push vadim master:refs/remotes/from-fedor/master
```

... and then have a `post-receive` hook on `Vadim` that:

1. Exits unless the ref being updated is `refs/remotes/from-fedor/master`
2. Exits in error unless `git status` is clean (i.e. `git status --porcelain` is empty)
3. Runs `git reset --hard refs/remotes/from-fedor/master`

The stage where you check that `git status` is clean could also be inserted into [VonC's suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348135/how-do-i-go-about-with-this-git-configuration-which-pushes-to-production-from-the/5348379#5348379) as well - that's nice because if someone has been naughtily playing with the deployed repository on `Vadim`, it will won't overwrite any changes that person made.

If it's not clear to you how to write such a hook, let me know in the comments and I'll write and test an example.

While it's quite correct that it's not generally suggested that you push into a bare repository, the [git FAQ has an example](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#push-is-reverse-of-fetch) of the method I've suggested here, where you push directly to a ref that *looks like* a remote-tracking branch in the remote repository.

---

**Update**:

In answer to the points you raise in the comments below:

- Yes, in this setup there's just a bare repository on `Fedor` and a non-bare repository on `Vadim`.
- In the repository on `Fedor`, you would add a "remote" that points to the URL of the repository on `Vadim`.  In the example above I assumed that you'd called this `vadim` (i.e. in lower case) and you would add that with something like: `git remote add vadim ssh://vadim.whereever/respository/`
- The hook that you set up on `Fedor` should be a `post-receive` hook that might look something like:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  while read oldrev newrev refname
  do
      if [ x"$refname" = xrefs/heads/master ]
      then
          git push vadim master:refs/remotes/from-fedor/master
      fi
  done
  ```

  ... and make sure you remember to make that executable.

Comment: I admit I'm actually confused. So Fedor stays as a bare repo, and Vadim stays as a non-bare repo? Also, what type of hook would I add to Fedor? And how do I reference `vadim` from `Fedor`? Thanks for replying.